# "Failed to run constructor: ReferenceError: PluginManager is not defined" in Android PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

How do I stop the `Failed to run constructor: ReferenceError: PluginManager is not defined` error in PhoneGap  in Android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In version 1.0 of PhoneGap they changed the plugins mechanism.

The old way of adding plugins was in the `PhoneGap.addConstructor` part of the javascript file for the plugin.

You would have something like

```
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
   PhoneGap.addPlugin('analytics', new Analytics());
   PluginManager.addService("GoogleAnalyticsTracker", "com.phonegap.plugins.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker");
});
```

However in newer versions you now do the `addService` step inside the `res/xml/plugins.xml` file.

So in my case I was using the Google Analytics plugin which still uses the old method. It doesn't seem to do any harm being there as I think it just gets ignored. However, if you want to get rid of the error just comment out the `PluginManager.addService(.....)` line in your `analytics.js` file.